# Перевод кода с Kotlin на Java

Tags: java, kotlin, exoplayer

Имею код на Kotlin (Android Studio 3.5):

```
Class RadioPlayerActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var player: SimpleExoPlayer
private lateinit var mediaSource: MediaSource
private lateinit var dataSourceFactory: DefaultDataSourceFactory

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio_player)

    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this)

    dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "OnAir"))

    mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(RADIO_URL))

    with(player) {
        prepare(mediaSource)
        btnStart.setOnClickListener {
            playWhenReady = true
        }

        btnStop.setOnClickListener {
            playWhenReady = false
        }
    }

}

override fun onDestroy() {
    player.playWhenReady = false
    super.onDestroy()
}

companion object {
    const val RADIO_URL = "http://s1.radioheart.ru:8001/radiogomelfm"
```

Переписываю на Java (Android Studio 3.5):

```
public class RadioPlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SimpleExoPlayer player;
private DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory;
private MediaSource mediaSource;
private Boolean playWhenReady;
static String RADIO_URL = "http://s1.radioheart.ru:8001/radiogomelfm";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio_player);
    playWhenReady = false;


    player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
    dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "OnAir"));
    mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(RADIO_URL));
}

public void OnStart(View view){
    player.prepare(mediaSource);
    playWhenReady = true;
}

public void OnStop(View view){
    playWhenReady = false;
}
}
```

В первом случае поток воспроизводится. В коде на Java - молчание. Что не так?

Comment: Вы забыли перевести на яву код, отвечающий за подготовку плеера и за назначение слушателей нажатий: `with(player) {
        prepare(mediaSource)
        btnStart.setOnClickListener {
            playWhenReady = true
        }

        btnStop.setOnClickListener {
            playWhenReady = false
        }
    }`

Comment: Т.е. в этих строчках все нормально?player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this);
    dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "OnAir"));
    mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(Uri.parse(RADIO_URL));

Comment: И еще вопрос: player.prepare(mediaSource); как это правильно переписать на  Java? У меня здесь ступор.

Comment: Переписал (методом тыка, здесь сорри)    public void OnStart(View view){
        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

    }

    public void OnStop(View view){
        if (player!=null){
            player.stop();
        }
    }
}

Comment: 1. Да, вроде всё верно. 2. Надо как-то так: `prepare(mediaSource); btnStart.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            playWhenReady = true
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            playWhenReady = false
        });`
3. Это не должно работать. Методы всегда с маленькой и вы вместо ненужного, вроде, переопределения создали методы, которые никогда никем не вызваются.

Comment: Хм.. сейчас попробую.

Comment: Сделал так:     public void OnStart(View view) {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    public void OnStop(View view) {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    }

Comment: Все заработало. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Переписал код в Java:

```
public void OnStart(View view) 
{ 
player.setPlayWhenReady(true); 
} 

public void OnStop(View view) 
{ 
player.setPlayWhenReady(false); 
}
```